# get raw rfc822 message from phpmailer

Tags: gmail, phpmailer, google-api-php-client

I am trying to use google-api-php-client and gmail-api to allow my users to authenticate their gmail accounts and send emails through my website.  I [asked a more generic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940984/send-email-using-gmail-api-and-google-api-php-client) earlier and decided to seek help from the PHPMailer community with this question.

I have used PHPMailer to send emails.  And I want to know if I can extract the raw rfc822 message from my PHPMailer object after setting it up prior to sending.  I should be able to then do a base64_encode on that string and set the "raw" property for my Google_Service_Gmail_Message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No problem: Set up everything as if you were going to send, but instead of calling `send()`, call `preSend()`, then fetch the complete message using `getSentMIMEMessage()`.