# Gmail PHP API Sending Email

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am trying to send an email through the Gmail PHP API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send). Everything seems to work up to the point that I send the message. My code is:

```
private function createMessage($email) {
    $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
     $message->setRaw(strtr(base64_encode($email), '+/=', '-_,'));      // $email is a raw email data string
    return $message;
}

public function sendMessage($userID, $email) {
    try {
        $msg = $this->createMessage($email);
        $this->service->users_messages->send($userID, $msg);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The code is breaking at the line:

`$this->service->users_messages->send($userID, $msg);`

with the error:

```
An error occurred: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/myemailaddress@gmail.com/messages/send: (400) Invalid value for ByteString:
```

Any idea what is happening here? Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide example with full raw message you sending? I have difficulty to send emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email string you set to 'raw' needs to be *url safe* base64 encoded (slightly different alphabet).

Answer (score 5):

The problem, like Eric said, is the url safe base 64. You need to change the url conversion to something more like this:

```
$message_object = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$encoded_message = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode("PUT MESSAGE HERE"), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$message_object->setRaw($encoded_message);
```

Also make sure to use a valid [mail mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631856/mime-type-to-satisfy-html-email-images-and-plain-text), so "PUT MESSAGE HERE" would not work in reality. You'll need to include valid headers like subject, etc. There are [some various PHP libraries](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime) to make these, or if you can make it yourself in plain text.