# Invalid value for ByteString error when calling gmail send API with base64 encoded < or >

Tags: gmail

Really stuck on this one and pulling my hair out trying to figure out what to do, searched everywhere and tried everything but still stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

So I am calling the Gmail send message API:

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send

I pass in the following base64 encoded raw message:

> VG86IGVjaG9zaWduLnNmZGMucWFAZ21haWwuY29tDQpTdWJqZWN0OiBSZTogd2UgaGF2ZSBhIGNvb2wgcHJvZHVjdA0KSW4tUmVwbHktVG86IDxDQUFMRnBBSmc1aTJlQ1p4T2dQWlhUdnNaN0J5M0gzNlRCMkNQYTdoVEtzTXh2bXZfT3dAbWFpbC5nbWFpbC5jb20+DQpSZWZlcmVuY2VzOiA8Q0FBTEZwQUpnNWkyZUNaeE9nUFpYVHZzWjdCeTNIMzZUQjJDUGE3aFRLc014dm12X093QG1haWwuZ21haWwuY29tPg0KDQoxMTozNg==

Which decodes to:

```
To: echosign.sfdc.qa@gmail.com
Subject: Re: we have a cool product
In-Reply-To: <CAALFpAJg5i2eCZxOgPZXTvsZ7By3H36TB2CPa7hTKsMxvmv_Ow@mail.gmail.com>
References: <CAALFpAJg5i2eCZxOgPZXTvsZ7By3H36TB2CPa7hTKsMxvmv_Ow@mail.gmail.com>

11:36
```

I get the error:

> Status code: 400 and status: Bad Request and response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid", "message": "Invalid value for ByteString

The problem is the less than `<` and greater than `>` symbols in the In-Reply-To and References headers. I need those headers because I am trying to have the email come as a reply on the thread. I tried to leave out the `<` and `>` but the reply then does not thread.

Thanks

Comment: Is it url safe base64 encoded?

Comment: I have tried to encode the email as URL safe with UTF-8, but does not help. Do you know what I should replace the < and > with to make it go across the wire?

Comment: Actually justt ried it again and if encoded then it did send across, but the reply did not show up up as a reply, no previosu conversation included. Does this look correct?

To: echosign.sfdc.qa@gmail.com
Subject: Re: we have a cool product
In-Reply-To: %3C089e01538a1223ee380506ab2157%40google.com%3E
References: %3C089e01538a1223ee380506ab2157%40google.com%3E

hi there

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using PHP try this (otherwise try converting it to whatever language you are using)

Call the below function on your mime message before setting it to the raw property.

```
private function base64url_encode($mime) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($mime), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
```

Comment: One quick and dirty way to do this in golang (comments won't let me format as code):

    b64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(msg)
    b64 = strings.Replace(b64, "+", "-", -1)
    b64 = strings.Replace(b64, "-", "_", -1)
    message.Raw = strings.TrimRightFunc(b64, unicode.IsSpace)

Comment: Actually, all golang needs is ``RawURLEncoding`` instead of ``StdEncoding``:

message.Raw:= base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(msg)

Answer (score 24):

From Google's gmail rest api (sending messages):

"The entire email message in an RFC 2822 formatted and **base64url** encoded string. Returned in messages.get and drafts.get responses when the format=RAW parameter is supplied."

base64**url** encoding is not the same as base64 encoding.

in python, the base64 library offers b64encode() and urlsafe_b64encode(). If you don't use urlsafe_b64encode(), you will get that error, not all the time so it may pass a simple unit test, but it will fail soon enough.

Comment: For Java 8: Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(bytes)

Answer (score 6):

In Google Apps Script following fixes the issue

```
var draftBody = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(raw);
```

**Don't use** `var draftBody = Utilities.base64Encode(raw);`

Answer (score 5):

The Google API decodes with `urlsafe_b64decode`. Try to use `urlsafe_b64encode` (encode strings using a URL-safe alphabet, which uses `-` instead of `+` and `_` instead of `/` in the standard Base64 alphabet.)

In your example I see one `+` which means you used standard Base64.

Answer (score 4):

**After** you encode your message contents via `base64Encode`, like here (assuming google script):

```
var draftBody =  Utilities.base64Encode(message_content_string);
```

you have to convert all `'/'` and `'+'` characters that are **not 'web-safe'** and will produce the *"Invalid value for ByteString"* error. You can do it this way:

```
draftBody = draftBody.replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');
```

Then you submit it as a raw data. Apparently there is no distortion of message contents here.